# How to center a NavigationRail's content in Jetpack Compose (menuGravity missing)

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-jetpack-compose

**Problem**

The Composable `androidx.compose.material.NavigationRail` has in some documention an optional "centered" alignment. I cannot achieve this using Jetpack Compose.

The "old" XML attribute is `app:menuGravity="center"` [according to this tutorial](https://joebirch.co/android/exploring-the-material-navigation-rail/).

**Things I tried without success**

I tried to put the NavigationRail (a simple wrapper for the actual widget) in a Box with an alignment set:

```
Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
    NavigationRail(
        selectedItem = selectedItem,
        onSelectItem = { selectedItem = it }
    )
}
```

and putting it directly into the original Composable:

```
NavigationRail(
    modifier = modifier.width(80.dp),
    backgroundColor = MaterialTheme.colors.surface
) {
   Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
       for (item in NavigationItem.values()) {
      NavigationRailItem(
          selected = selectedItem == item,
          onClick = { onSelectItem.invoke(item) },
          icon = { Icon(item.icon, item.title) },
          alwaysShowLabel = true,
          selectedContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primaryVariant,
          unselectedContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
          label = { Text(item.title, modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 8.dp)) }
      )
       }
   }
}
```

**Screenhot**
(taken from the same site as the linked tutorial)

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested in the [example](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/compose/material/material/samples/src/main/java/androidx/compose/material/samples/NavigationRailSample.kt) to center the navigationRail's content you can use something like:

```
NavigationRail {
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
    items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        NavigationRailItem(
            //....
        )
    }
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
}
```

To achieve a Bottom alignment just use a `Spacer`:

```
NavigationRail {
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
    items.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        NavigationRailItem(
            //....
        )
    }
}
```

[image]